# Cannot receive updates or finish upgrading after interrupted 12.04 install

Tags: upgrade, updates, 12.04

The problem started when I was trying to download the 12.04 Beta 1 but didn't have sufficient time to complete the install. As I try to upgrade or re-download 12.04 I get the message "Not all updates can be installed" with the choice to Partial Upgrade or close.

Partial Upgrade gives me:

> An upgrade from 'precise' to 'oneiric' is not supported with this
>   tool.

Close gives me:

> Software index is broken
>
> It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the
>   package manager "Synaptic" or run "sudo apt-get install -f" in a
>   terminal to fix this issue at first.

The Synaptic suggestion doesn't work as well. The command gives me

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can open a terminal and enter `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me:

```
sudo -i
```

and then

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

That worked, and I could now run the command:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: i had shutdown the system due to hang up when it was upgrading ubuntu. the system didnt start up. then i restored to earlier-> dwonloaded broken packages but not able to upgrade-> it said no latest version available n the upgrade had not completed. so finally followed this n it worked. so, +1